# How to search and remove ^M in all files in a directory recursively?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Files edited in Windows have M^ at end lines. How would I remove them ?

Comment: Any decent text editor can do this for you - did you have a programming question ?

Comment: See last word in headline.

Comment: @amdixon I have not installed dos2unix, and would not / cannot install one .

Comment: @PaulR I an not able to do it in a (any) text editor coz. I need to check a complete project, which means thousands of files. Not sensible to go through each file / directory manually.

Comment: @maan81: if you have a decent text editor then you can just point it at a directory and tell it to do a global search and replace recursively - I do this all the time with BBEdit - I'm sure there must be editors with similar capabilities on Linux. Again, this isn't really a programming question, so it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @PaulR Really, thank you maan. :-) IDEs would/could certainly solve the problem. I guess I should the mentioned I needed a bash script without any additional requirements.

Comment: @maan81: yes, it's always good to be specific as to what you need when you ask a question - it saves everyone a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @PaulR Well, I assumed the StackOverflow's tags would be enough. I didnt use the IDE's or anything similar, and used bash, shell & Ubuntu. Probably I should have used Linux.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> **NOTE**
>
> Be careful when using this command, as it will replace *all* LF/CR
>   character sequence regardless of position or context. Take extra care
>   in situations where you have binary files or files that have special
>   configuration formats. Directories with git submodules is an example
>   that will likely have problems with this command, as the character
>   sequence has already been stored as persistent commits.

It is a control code for carriage return. Windows uses the LF/CR notation for line delimiters, while UNIX systems used only LF.

Below should do it for all files recursively down the file system tree relative to the current directory.

```
find . -type f | xargs -Ix sed -i.bak -r 's/\r//g' x
```

The code above will make automatic backups (with extension `.bak` appended to the file name).

Once you made sure the files are good, use the following to delete the backups.

```
find . -type f -name '*.bak' | xargs -Ix rm x
```

Comment: `x > x`? A safe solution to destroy all files. Take a look at sed's `-i` option.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for pointing this out, I've changed it to use the `-i` option in `sed`.

Comment: @tchen Thank you very much. I know about the problem with carriage return and the windows & linux format. I wanted a way to correct the problem. I had done a number of google searches but I was not satisfied with the output.  :-)

Comment: Do not use this command if you have git submodule inside the directory.

Comment: @AlexBender and in case it happened...? I just did such a great thing and having hard time recovering (and I don't have even have a remote repo).

Comment: @Paolo if you used the commands as-is, it should have made `.bak` files automatically. You can just replace the new files with the `.bak` files.

Comment: Ok, I did... I had to replace > 20000 files. This is how: `find -iname \*.* | rename -v -f "s/\.bak//g"`. Nothing lost, HTH

Comment: @Paolo I've updated the answer with a note about this at the top.

Comment: Is there a way to have it ignore the `.git` folder?

Comment: @AaronFranke Yes, there are a few ways you can ignore the `.git` directory. One way is to explicitly list the directories you _do_ want to include (e.g. `find a/ b/ -type f ...`; or even `find * -type f ...`, provided that your shell does _not_ expand `*` to hidden files, and that you have no hidden files of your own). I believe `find` has some flags to ignore certain patterns as well, such as the `-regex` flag.

Comment: This answer gave problems when aplied to git folders, what I used was https://superuser.com/questions/684017/removing-carriage-returns-m-from-certain-lines-without-modifying-every-line just in case anyone else is here for the same reason